# Using the official Nextcloud Docker image, how do I run occ commands as www-data inside Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, nextcloud

I've tried many different commands, including:

```
RUN sudo -u www-data /var/www/html/occ etc...
```

and:

```
RUN ["sudo -u www-data /var/www/html/occ", "etc..."]
```

and:

```
USER www-data
RUN /var/www/html/occ etc...
```

All of these result in the same message:

> ERROR: Service 'core' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"sudo -u www-data /var/www/html/occ maintenance:install\": stat sudo -u www-data /var/www/html/occ maintenance:install: no such file or directory": unknown

Could this be that `occ` is not in its place until the container's first run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. You can't run occ command until nextcloud is installed. And it will be installed on run a container in enrtypoint.sh

Comment: New to Docker. I didn't even know entrypoint.sh was a thing. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks.